# Equivalent definition of sigma algebra

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I have seen that this two definitions when adding any arbitrary set $S\subset X$, (X-metric space), to the $\sigma$-algebra $A_0$, are equivalent. But for me is not immediate.

" The sigma algebra generated by $(A_0 ∪ \{S\})$, denote by $\sigma (A_0 ∪ \{S\})$, coincides with the collection of all sets of the form $E = (A ∩ S) ∪ (B ∩ (X \setminus  S))$, where $A, B \in A_0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**:
Let $\mathcal A_S$ denote the collection of all sets of the form $(A \cap S) \cup (B \cap (X \setminus  S))$ for some $A,B\in A_0$.  Clearly $\mathcal A_S\subset\sigma(A_0\cup\{S\})$.  For the reverse inclusion, show that $\mathcal A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, such that $A_0\subset\mathcal A_S$ and $S\in\mathcal A_S$.

Comment: given the hint, the only problem for me is to show the $A_0 \subset A_s$ part. The condition means that $ \forall D \in A_0$ we can write $D = (A ∩ S) ∪ (B ∩ (X \setminus  S))$. right?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: is that just by letting $A=\emptyset$ and $B=D$?

Comment: I think $A=B=D$ works