# Extending measure on $\mathcal{A}$ to $\sigma\big(\mathcal{A} \cup\{N\}\big)$ - proof verification and Intuition

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

Let $\lambda$ be the Lebesgue measure on $[0, 1]$ and $\mathcal{A}$ be the $\sigma$-algebra of Lebesgue measurable sets in $[0, 1]$. Suppose that a set $N \subset [0, 1]$ is not in $\mathcal{A}$. Prove that $\lambda$ can be extended to a measure on a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}$ that contains $\mathcal{A}$ and
$N$.

Is the below $\textbf{attempt}$ correct:

I only need to show that $\lambda$ is measure on the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}=\sigma\big(\mathcal{A} \cup\{N\}\big)$.

let $E\in \mathcal{B}$, given that $\lambda$ is measure on $\mathcal{A}$ it follows that $\lambda\geq0$ and $\lambda(\phi)=0$ is satisfied.  So I only need to show that it also satisfies the $\sigma$-additivity. I remember the following lemma from of my homeworks;,

$\textbf{BUT}$ have no intuition about the lemma, (how would I can think of solving this question without knowing the following lemma?)

lemma: All sets $E \in \sigma\big(\mathcal{A} \cup\{N\}\big)$ can be written as $E = (A\cap N) \cup (B\cap N^c)$ where $A,B \in \mathcal{A}$. 
(I skip the proof, but can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3370368/equivalent-definition-of-sigma-algebra))

So given above; let $\{E_i\}_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a collection of disjoint sets in $\mathcal{B}$.

\begin{align}
\lambda \bigg(\bigcup_{i\in \mathbb{N}}E_i\bigg) 
& =  \lambda \bigg(\bigcup_{i\in \mathbb{N}}A_i\cap N) \cup (B_i\cap N^c)\bigg)\\
& = \sum_{i\in \mathbb{N}}\lambda \bigg((A_i\cap N) \cup (B_i\cap N^c)\bigg)\\
& = \sum_{i\in \mathbb{N}}\lambda (E_i) \\
\end{align}

where the second equality follows from the fact $(A_i\cap N),(B_i\cap N^c)\in \mathcal{A}$, as $A_i,B_i \in \mathcal{A}$ and $\lambda$ is measure on $\mathcal{A}$. Also that $(A_i\cap N) \cap (B_i\cap N^c)= \phi $

Comment: First of all, if you extend $\lambda$, then which value do you assign to $\lambda(N)$? Moreover, how can you know, that $$\lambda(\bigcup (A_i \cap N) \cup (B_i \cap N^c)) = \sum \lambda((A_i \cap N) \cup (B_i \cap N^c))$$ You don't know if your new $\lambda$ satisfies this condition, since this is what you set out to prove in the first place. I am quite convinced, the result you set out to prove is false (take a look at the construction of the Vitali set for instance)